# Divs are not moving and creating new space when I add new content like slideshow, heading, etc

Tags: spacing

[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMXAQ.png)I am making a personal website, and I am trying to add a slideshow in between a div and the footer, but when I try it always goes to the upper left corner, and it stays behind the div and footer. It doesn't create space in between the div and footer like it should, so if anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

I tried using the z-index method, but that only brought the slideshow forward it didn't create space for the slideshow in between the div and footer.